# How did Faraday determine the Faraday's constant?

Tags: physics, experimental-physics, chemistry

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_laws_of_electrolysis) is the reference. I'm wondering how he experimentally proceeded to derive the fact the if we pass 96485 Coulombs through a solution, then 1 gram equivalent of substance is electrolyzed.

Comment: Details are on the Wiki, first reference. This is too broad of a question. I think what you might be interested in, from my previous answer, is how did he determine the so-called Faraday constant in his own time. This is the number which allowed e/m.

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I’m looking for.

Comment: The answer to your query is in Experimental Electrochemistry By Nevil Monroe Hopkins · 1905. It is beautifully described on page 80 onwards. The book is freely available from Google Books